# libGDX blender normal mapped material not correctly converted by fbx-conv

Tags: libgdx

I've textured a cube in blender 2.6. I assigned a color map from file cube.png to the cube. I assigned a normal map from file bump.png to the cube. I set the normal map to be a normal map and to influence normals. Blender displays the normal mapping correctly. I've then used fbx-conv 0.01 with option -o g3dj to get a readable file. The only warning I got was the RrSs thingie, which afaik can be safely ignored. I then opened the file to inspect the result. The texture structure does not reflect the normal map:

```
"materials": [
    {
        "id": "Material", 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Material__bump_png", 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "bump_png", 
                "filename": "bump.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

So basically it exports the last texture of the texture stack, and it exports it with standard settings, not as a diffuse map.

What do I have to do (in Blender settings, I suppose) to have normal mapping exported correctly using fbx-conv?

[3D Model with Diffuse AND Normalmap texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073933/3d-model-with-diffuse-and-normalmap-texture) suggests that normal map export should be supported. probably I am doing something wrong in blender?

thanks a lot

Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

We do have problems with the exported Models from Blender as well. And I have never seen the fbx-conv exporting the normal map correctly (probably, cause I am doing smth. wrong)

a solution would be to convert the fbx into g3dj, put in the normal map manually.

```
    }, 
    {
        "id": "stone_phong", 
        "diffuse": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000], 
        "specular": [ 0.204000,  0.163487,  0.079152], 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "file5", 
                "filename": "rock_diff.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            },
            {
                "id": "stone_norm", 
                "filename": "rock_norm.png", 
                "type": "NORMAL"
            }
        ]
    },
```

as described in the [tutorial from xoppa](http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part1/). And use g3dj for testing. afaik fbx-conv can convert g3dj into g3db as well.

The disappointing thing you'll figure out, is that it still does not use the normal maps in the shader.

[Edit:] A closer look in the G3ModelLoader tells me that instead of NORMAPMAP you have to use NORMAL to make the loader associate the normal texture attribute as such. I corrected that in the g3dj example above